# Pausing song when a video begins playing (and vice-versa)

Tags: ios, interrupt, avplayer

I have an app that uses AVPlayer to play songs and a UIWebView to play YouTube videos.  When I build it against iOS 5, the audio and video refuse to play together, which I like.  Pressing play on one will automatically pause the other, with a nice half-second fade-out.

Now that I'm building against iOS 6, this behavior is gone -- the songs and videos play over each other.  How can I get back the iOS 5 behavior?

Answer (score 0):

add the shared categories in your App delegate:

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
```

this will limit to only one active audio session

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  I tried inserting the code in a few different places including `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.  The errors always come back nil.  The video and audio still play simultaneously.

Comment: ok, then can't you handle this manually ? delegate the method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType` and pause the audio before returning YES there.

Comment: You're right, that will probably cover 50% of use cases.  But what if the user begins playing music before the video ends?  And now the audio will silence as soon as the page loads, even if there is a buffering delay before the video starts.